Thermal fuse replacement
I need to replace a failed thermal fuse, but I cannot match a replacement exactly.  I need a ShengPing SPF70-73C, TH=45C, TM=115C/10a @ 250v.  How close do I have to match these specs, over and/or under?

Suggest add more info: a photo, dimensions, and what the fuse was protecting would be very useful info.

This thermal fuse is a cylinder, about 3/4 in, with an orange cap on one end and has a lead on both ends.  It's used in a small 4.5cf Frigidaire refrigerator and protects the defroster from over heating.

What voltage are you operating this refrigerator on?  And is it AC or DC?
